# How do I solve the clock room?

Tags: fez

There's a room with a huge clock in the temple/science warp zone. I think I just have to wait until something appears, but how long should I wait?

[image: clock tower]

Answer (score 26):

There are four anticubes in the clock puzzle. Each will show when one of the clock's four hands hit the top. There is a limited window for catching the anticube before it disappears. The times differ between consoles, but the hands' speeds are the same:

- Red cycles every minute.
- Blue cycles hourly.
- Green cycles daily (24 hours).
- Gray cycles every week (7 days).

You'll need to check your clock and figure when it'll hit the top. Either check back then or change your 360's time from the system settings (you'll need to disconnect from the Internet).

E.g., my blue always hit at :15 past the hour, my green always hit at 7 p.m. (once a day), and my gray hit at 4 a.m. with a rather large window (since it moves slowly).

[image: green clock, cycles daily]

Comment: Interestingly, my grey hit at Jan 6th, 8:12 am.  I thought this was based on another clue, but I guess it was coincidence?

Comment: For me it hits: 3rd June 2020, 6:00 pm (London timezone)

Answer (score 6):

Some people on other forums are saying the grey/white is every 48 hours. It's definitely more than that!

These:

[image]

[image]

[image]

...are a difference of sixteen to twenty hours between each. By my own estimates based off each quarter of the clock being *roughly* 40 hours, that means a total of roughly 160 hours give or take a dozen or so, meaning the 7-day estimate appears to be correct.

Maybe it's different between the PC and the XBox versions, I don't know.

Note: If you change your PC's time, you have to exit Fez and then start it back up. You'll still be in the clock-tower room, but you'd be at the bottom of the tower.

Unlike the Xbox, you *don't* need to disable your internet connection on your PC if you are adjusting your PC's clock.

Supposedly, on the PS4, you can just go to your time settings and use the 'Change Manually' option; when you go back to Fez the hands will have moved the correct amount. You don't need to quit out just use the PS button to go to the menu then back again. I'm not sure if this is true though.

Comment: I got the green cube around 6pm I think, and the white hand was pointing down, but a little to the right. I expected the white cube to be at 6pm as well, but I got it quite a bit earlier in the day; I think it was about three days later. So I'm not entirely convinced that 7 days is exactly right either... unless the white cube has a much bigger window of opportunity to grab it. Still, it does seem to be at least close to 7 days.

Comment: Regarding PS4, yes this is true... just tried it :-)

Answer (score 2):

For the clock room you just have to wait until each hand reaches the 12:00  postition on their perspective. From what I've seen they move at different speeds. From fastest to slowest is: Red, being the seconds hand. Blue, most likely minutes hand. Green, I am guessing hour hand. White, I have no clue, but I hope it isn't a days hand.

Answer (score 1):

The white hand of the clock creates an anticube around 12:00 noon, so try setting your 360's clock to a few minutes before that (after disconnecting from Xbox Live). As far as I know it activates at noon regardless of how often you've visited the clock or when you started the game.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking,considering that I have solved the half the puzzle so far,
Red=Minutely
Blue=Hourly
Green=Daily(12:00 a.m./12:00 p.m.
White=Possibly every 12 days