# How long is the day to night cycle in Fez?

Tags: fez

In Fez I was playing with the giant telescope trying to solve the puzzle, but suddenly it turned to day and I can't see anything useful.  How long do I have to wait for it to turn to night?

Comment: Either way you're going to have to wait, so just time it on your own.

Comment: It's been a while since I did that puzzle, but I recall it being long enough to wait out.  Similar to the [clock puzzle](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/62477/21619), and easier solution is to just change the time of your console or PC.

Answer (score 4):

The entire day/night cycle seems to be around 5'30", or 330 seconds. The red blinking stars will be visible for around 1'45", or 105 seconds.