# There’s only one hand on my Fez Clock

Tags: fez

I’ve gotten 4 anti cubes, but only three of the are from the clock (I think). I know how to get the anti cubes, but now my clock only has ONE HAND... I don’t know what that means or what I should do...

Comment: It's been a long time since I played Fez, but don't you have to rotate the room to see the other clock hands?

Answer (score 2):

If you've already collected three anti-cubes from the Clock Room, then the clock itself is correctly displaying only one hand - each one of the cubes you collect will cause its corresponding hand to briefly flash and disappear.

Check this YT video at (0:23) for a demonstration of this effect:

[image: IMAGE ALT TEXT HERE]

If you need a reference on which clock hand you still have active, [this old Arqade question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/62477/how-do-i-solve-the-clock-room/62592) has a list of each hand and their estimated time cycle.